# how do i select the row in the list view using custom adapter

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I am not able to figure out a way to select row in the listview  using Custom Adapter

```
   Adapter class

    public class HouseHoldExpenceAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    implements View.OnClickListener {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<HouseHoldExpence>houseHoldExpences;
    private Context context;
    public static  final  String ecategory="new_category";
    public  static  final String econtent="new_content";
    public static  final String  edate="new_date";
    public  static  final String esum="expence_sum";
    public  static  final  String e_id="expenceId";

    public HouseHoldExpenceAdapter(Context  
    context,List<HouseHoldExpence> houseHoldExpences)
    {
    this.houseHoldExpences=houseHoldExpences;
    this.context=context;
   }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return   houseHoldExpences.size();
    }

    @Override
    public HouseHoldExpence getItem(int position) {
    return houseHoldExpences.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   
    parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

   if(row==null)
   {
       layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.householdexpence, null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder(row);
       viewHolder.textViewCategory=
    (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.category);
       viewHolder.textViewContent = (TextView)  
    row.findViewById(R.id.conntent);
       viewHolder.textviewSum = (TextView)   
    row.findViewById(R.id.totalSum);
       row.setTag(viewHolder);

   }
    else
   {
       viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
   }
    viewHolder.textViewCategory.setTextColor(Color.RED);

   viewHolder.textViewCategory.setText
   (houseHoldExpences.get(position).getCategory());
     viewHolder.textViewContent.setText
   (String.valueOf(houseHoldExpences.get(position).getContent()));
    viewHolder.textviewSum.setText(String.
   valueOf(houseHoldExpences.get(position).getSum()));
    viewHolder.DeleteButton.setTag(position);
    viewHolder.updateButton.setTag(position);

    viewHolder.textViewCategory.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    viewHolder.textViewContent.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    viewHolder.textviewSum.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    row.setOnClickListener(this);
    return  row;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    //How to call updateExpence(int position)

   }


    private class ViewHolder
    {
     TextView textViewCategory;
    TextView textViewContent;
    TextView textviewSum;
    ImageButton DeleteButton;
    Button updateButton;
    private ViewHolder(View view) {

        updateButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Update);
        DeleteButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Delete);


        DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Delete entry")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete 

       this entry?")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new   

     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface 
      dialog, int which) {
                                remove((int)v.getTag());
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new    
      DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface 
     dialog, int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .show();



            }
        });

    //   updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //   @Override
    //    public void onClick(final View v) {
    //
   //
   //  updateExpence((int) v.getTag());
   /  /                }
   //            });
      }
  }

     public  void updateExpence(int position)

   {

    HouseHoldExpence houseHoldExpence=houseHoldExpences.get(position);

    Intent intent=new Intent(context, HouseHoldExpence_update.class);
    intent.putExtra(ecategory,houseHoldExpence.getCategory());
    intent.putExtra(econtent,houseHoldExpence.getContent());
    intent.putExtra(edate,houseHoldExpence.getDate());
    intent.putExtra(esum, houseHoldExpence.getSum());
    intent.putExtra(e_id, houseHoldExpence.getId());
    context.startActivity(intent);
     }

    public void remove(int  position)
    {
     HouseHoldExpence  
      houseHoldExpence=houseHoldExpences.get(position);
    DatabaseManager.getInstance(context)
   .deleteHoudeHoldeExpence(houseHoldExpence);
    houseHoldExpences.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

     public  void setHouseHoldExpence
     (List<HouseHoldExpence>houseHoldExpence)
     {
     this.houseHoldExpences=houseHoldExpence;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
   }
```

}

Am using list view with custom adapter
its displaying all list items  when i click a row in the list view  how to call update method and pass the position  present in the adapter class.. anyone please help  me....

Comment: post yout `houseHoldExpenceAdapter` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in the adapter class

 viewHolder.textViewCategory.setTag(position);
 row.setOnClickListener(this);


 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {


  //How to call updateExpence(int position)
   ViewHolder  viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();;
    int i= (int) viewHolder.textViewCategory.getTag();

    updateExpence(i);

  }
```

this will work......

Answer (score 0):

find the view in your `getView()` of your row , and `setOnClickListener` on it.
write the code of onClick in your adapter's `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

you are implementing wrong listener. you should do implement OnItemClickListener

> public class HouseHoldExpenceAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
>       implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener

this will ask you to implement a class which provides view and position of item clicked

```
 @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     //postion is the position of clicked item
     // call the method from here
}
```

Try to implement OnItemCLickListener in the class which have your list view. This makes job easier. Well atleast for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the OnItemClickListener and assign it to the listview.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new CustomOnItemClickListener());
```

A full code example can be found here: [Get Selected Items from ListView](http://kb4dev.com/tutorial/android-listview/checkbox-in-listview--event-handling--1)